# Ensemble, merge or combine multiple lmertree objects

Tags: multilevel-analysis, cart, bagging

Working with the PISA data, which includes multiple achievement scores (plausible values) for each participant, I would like to run the same `lmertree` and ensemble the results.

```r
lmm_treeM01 <- lmertree(PV1MATH~ 1 | schid | X1 + X2)

lmm_treeM02 <- lmertree(PV2MATH~ 1 | schid | X1 + X2)
```

Is it possible to combine `lmm_treeM01` and `lmm_treeM02`?

My manual bagging attempts failed.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.